# perl automatic module loading like in php

Tags: perl, module, autoload

I am creating a bigger application in Perl, and I am wondering whether something like class autoloading similar to php’s can be done in Perl?

I checked catching exceptions and $`SIG{__DIE__}` redefining etc., but this doesn't seem to be solution because it will be stopped on first “cannot find method new via package”, and then to load every module I should again call the whole program.

One solution could be to maybe scan all files in my lib and give it to `@INC` at runtime, but I don’t know whether this is good solution — probably not.

Do anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you probably want to read up on the following:

- [AUTOLOAD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) and [AutoLoader](http://perldoc.perl.org/AutoLoader.html)
- [autouse](https://metacpan.org/module/autouse)
- [Class::AutoUse](https://metacpan.org/module/Class::Autouse)
- [later](https://metacpan.org/module/later)
- etc.

None of those are quite the same as PHP's approach though.

However, it really is best practice to list all "normal" dependencies. This makes it easier to build installers / deploy to CPAN etc. There are a bunch of other modules that deal with loading plugins, where you really don't know what to load until runtime.

Is there some difficulty with figuring out your dependencies, or do you just want to avoid a bunch of "use" statements at the top of each file?

Comment: Hi, yes i seen autoloader and autouse already, that lazy loading it's nice thing for performance, yes that's my goal to avoid just a big bunch of use statements, but i must admit that sometimes is good to have a list of dependencies listed like that

Comment: In that case, I'd say just get used to using "use". Anyone else looking at your code will be expecting it. You can bundle modules up into a common set though - see metacpan for Toolkit, Exporter::Cluster or look at the source for load_in_caller() in perl5i

Comment: i was just curious, i can't use anything from outside, because i am in corporate environment...but thanks for suggestions :)

Comment: You can still cut + paste the source from load_in_caller though. Or just read it and be "inspired" to write your own :-)

Comment: If I read your goal correctly, you could also just `require` the modules just before using them. That gets you lazy loading. You won't get any symbols exported, but it seems like you don't need that in this case.